# configsource and installer

Tags: installation, configsource

I have an project csproj, with app.config file, and logging Ent.Library  section using configsource attribute. The logging section is in ahother file Config\loggingconfiguration.config.

I have a Installer Project for this csproj. But when I generate , the file loggingconfiguration.config is NOT include.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check the properties of your file in the solution explorer? If you want to see it deployed the Build Action property should be "Content"